# List all the open urls on chrome via command prompt

Tags: google-chrome, cmd.exe

I want to list down all opened urls on chrome through command prompt.
Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you done research on what command line options Chrome offers to see if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I want a list of all opened URLs in Chrome through the command prompt. Is there any way I can do it?

A custom extension might do it (say via the tabs API), but I am uncertain if there would be a way to export URLs directly to the command line.

Another option might be something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). Selenium allows control of Chrome via third-party scripting languages. In short, you could (theoretically) write a command line script (say in [Python](https://www.python.org/)) that would start a Chrome session with Selenium, then allow you to query for and export URLs from the available tabs.

If you do choose the e.g. Selenium/Python route, I might also suggest [Ungoogled Chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium) builds from [Woolyss](https://chromium.woolyss.com/) (specifically the Marmaduke releases). Adding extensions requires a slightly different set of steps, but it is lightweight compared to Chrome, and includes a copy of the driver needed to interact with Selenium.

Comment: Thanks Anaksunaman!

Comment: You're welcome. =)